# WPF Keyboard Shortcut - Why is this not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard

I have the follwing code (which is not working):

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    e.Handled = true;
    if ((e.Key == Key.P) && (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt)) {
        MessageBox.Show("Thanks!");
    }            
}
```

Why doesn't this work? The event is firing, but

```
(e.Key == Key.P) && (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt))
```

never evaluates to true.
My similar events using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd> in this way work. Also my events that include <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> **and** <kbd>Alt</kbd> work as well.

Comment: Is the event itself not firing, or is the conditional not evaulating to true?

Comment: Opps! Will fix my question. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this a WPF app? If so what event/source is this, WPF 3.5 KeyEventArgs has no Modifiers property????

Comment: Yes, thank you. I just noticed that and corrected it. Running on too little sleep.

Comment: Title hint - try to capture the problem in the title, it will draw more attention that way!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to work with keys in WPF is [Key Gestures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keygesture.aspx)

e.g. **note that this is an example, not a solution**

```
<Window.InputBindings>
  <KeyBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" Gesture="ALT+P" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

There's more to it that that but you'll work it easily enough. That's the WPF way to handle keys!

PK  :-)

Comment: I've read a little about KeyBinding, but why is it that they are better than using keyevents?

Comment: The whole solution is to use in conjunction with ApplicationCommands etc. It's just a neater pattern. Also you can abstract commands etc. There is a little bit to it but I don't think you'll actually get the original way to work because of how the events  fire.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx for official info. Also take a look at http://en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Concepts%E2%80%94Controls_with_Built-In_Command_Bindings - it may help with the "why?"  :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help! And enduring my written question. It's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a 'bitwise and' with the `ModifierKeys` as shown below...

```
    private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Key == Key.P) && ((e.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) == ModifierKeys.Alt))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Thanks!");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Also, do not forget to set the `Handled` property of the `e` parameter...

Comment: I accidentally used e.Modifiers in my example code instead of  Keyboard.Modifiers, which is what I am actually using in my application. I apologize. I have not been able to get your example working with Keyboard.Modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN gives us this example:

```
if(e.Key == Key.P && e.Modifiers == Keys.Alt)
```

does this work for you?

Comment: As said by Paul Kohler: "WPF 3.5 KeyEventArgs has no Modifiers property" I mistakenly used e.Modifiers in my example code. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: I think a few of us were thrown by that! I thought it was a WinForms question at first :)